# Where's d2d1.h's source file?

Tags: idl, winapi, direct2d

The first few lines of `d2d1.h` in Windows SDK's that contain them (e.g. the one marked as v7.1) are as follows:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
//
// This file is automatically generated.  Please do not edit it directly.
//
// File name: D2D1.h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This indicates that there should be some source file somewhere. Is it included with the SDK, like the many IDL files? I couldn't find anything of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not included in the SDK. It's not public, to my knowledge, if it even exists (which, like you, I'd assume it does from that blurb in the header file).